# Is it possible to include same html template structure in PHP and JS files?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I’m developing a site which features some filter functionality. When the page is loaded, I have a custom WP_Query which loads some teasers.

```
<?php
$recipes = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'rezept',
    'orderby'           => 'menu_order'
));

if ($recipes->have_posts()) { ?>
    <div class="results grid grid--3-col">
        <?php while ($recipes->have_posts()) {
            $recipes->the_post();
            get_template_part('template-parts/content-recipe-teaser');
        } ?>
    </div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
```

Then I use a filter menu to exchange the teasers via jquery.getJSON() without reloading the whole page.

```
this.results.hide().append(`
            ${results.recipes.map(recipe => `
                <div class="teaser teaser--recipe">
                    <a class="teaser__image" href="${recipe.permalink}">
                        <img src="${recipe.thumbnail_url}">
                    </a>
                    <a class="teaser__title" href="${recipe.permalink}">
                        <h2>${recipe.title}</h2>
                    </a>
                    <h3 class="teaser--recipe__sauce" style="color: ${recipe.sauce_color}">
                        <span
                            class="color-swatch"
                            style="background-color: ${recipe.sauce_color}">
                        </span>
                        ${recipe.sauce_name}
                    </h3>
                    <p class="teaser__text">${recipe.excerpt}</p>
                    <a href="${recipe.permalink}" class="button">
                        <span class="button__text">Zum Rezept!</a>
                    </a>
                </div>
            `).join('')}
```

The html structure of the teasers is always the same, which is why I use get_template_part() to prevent code duplication. In my JavaScript file I also need the HTML structure of the teaser as a template for all the teasers to dynamically load via jQuery.getJSON(). But of course I can’t use get_template_part() in a js-file. Is there some way how I can prevent duplicate template code in php AND js-files? It’s somehow tedious to modify the template in php AND js when changes need to be done… What would you propose?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can store the template in a file and pass the content to [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to use it in JavaScript. and in PHP you use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) to replace `${recipe.sauce_color}` by the value.

Comment: or another way of doing that : on page load you send only data to JavaScript and Javascript renders everything, no more need of PHP template.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try both and figure out which is the easiest solution!